# Get what's in between the anchor tag that 's clicked

Tags: jquery, html

If I had something like:

```
<a>Content 1</a>
<a>Content 2</a>
<a>Content 3</a>
```

And I wanted to get the what's in between the anchor tags (the words being clicked), how would I go about that? The links are shown dynamically, so I can't add an `id` attribute to them. (I think I can't, at least.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work to select all:

```
$('a').each(function() { $(this).text(); /* do something with it */ });
```

if you want to get the click event on anchor tags, but only those without an id or class, try this:

```
$('a').not('a[id]').not('a[class]').click(function() { $(this).text(); ... });
```

and if you only want your action to be performed once:

```
$('a').not('a[id]').not('a[class]').one("click", function() { $(this).text(); ... });
```

Comment: I only want the content of the one clicked, though. Is that possible, while keeping the anchor tags like they are?

Comment: change .each to .click, somehow I missed the "clicked" part

Comment: Thanks. also added a couple more options in case you have other links on the page that you want to exclude.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any CSS selector that matches these tags to get a jQuery object for them.

You can then use [`text()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text) to get the contents of a tag in plain text, or [`html()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html) to get the direct html code, including any nested tags.

Example:

```
$('a').each(function() {
     alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the links are actually built dynamically once the page is already served to the client then you will want to wrap your `<a>` tags with an identifying element and then add an event listener to the wrapping element.

If you want this behavior for all the links on the page, then just use:

```
$('a').click(
   function() { 
      var link_text = $(this).text();
      //Do something with link_text 
   });
```